# How does this imply that $O_L/\mathfrak{p} O_L$ has non-zero nilpotent element?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, ramification

Let $O_K$ be the ring of integers of an algebraic number field $K$ and let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime in $O_K$. For a field extension $L/K$, we consider the ring of integer $O_L$ in $L$ and the ideal $\mathfrak{p} O_L$ of $O_L$. If $[L:K]< \infty$, then we have $$\mathfrak{p} O_L=\mathfrak{p}_1^{e_1} \mathfrak{p}_2^{e_2} \cdots \mathfrak{p}_n^{e_n},$$ where $\mathfrak{p}_i$ are distinct prime ideals of $O_L$.

Then $\mathfrak{p}$ ramifies in $L$ if some of $e_i>1$.

**My question:**

Why the above condition ($e_i>1$ for some $i$) is equivalent to say that $O_L/\mathfrak{p} O_L$ has a non-zero ${\color{blue}{nilpotent}}$ element ?

**Answer:**

Let $e_1=2>1$ and $\mathfrak{p} O_L=\mathfrak{p}_1^2$, where $\mathfrak{p}_1$ is the prime ideal in $O_L$.

How does this imply that $O_L/\mathfrak{p} O_L$ has non-zero nilpotent element ?

Comment: The elements in $\mathfrak{p}_1/\mathfrak{p}O_L$ are nilpotent.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, how to see explicitly that $O_L/\mathfrak{p} O_L$ has non-zero nilpotent elements when $e_i>1$ ? I am beginner. Can you left a short calculation showing this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the Chinese Remainder Theorem we have that

$$ \frac{O_L}{\mathfrak{p}_1^{e_1} \mathfrak{p}_2^{e_2} \cdots \mathfrak{p}_n^{e_n}} \cong \frac{O_L}{\mathfrak{p}_1^{e_1}} \times \cdots \times \frac{O_L}{\mathfrak{p}_n^{e_n}}.$$

If any $e_i$ is greater than $1$, then the quotient ring $\frac{O_L}{\mathfrak{p}_i^{e_i} }$ has a nonzero nilpotent element, namely, any element of $\mathfrak{p_i} - \mathfrak{p}_i^{e_i}$ modulo $\mathfrak{p}_i^{e_i}$. So the product also has a nonzero nilpotent element.

If all the $e_i$ are equal to $1$, then $\frac{O_L}{\mathfrak{p}_i^{e_i}}= \frac{O_L}{\mathfrak{p}_i}$ is a field. And a product of fields does not have any nonzero nilpotent elements.

Comment: What does it mean for an element $\bar{x}$, $x \in O_L$, to be nilpotent in $\frac{O_L}{\mathfrak{p}_i^{e_i} }$. It means there exists an $n$ such that $(\bar{x})^n = 0 \text{ in } \frac{O_L}{\mathfrak{p}_i^{e_i}}$, that is, $x^n \in \mathfrak{p}_i^{e_i}$. Now let $x \in \mathfrak{p}_i - \mathfrak{p}_i^{e_i}$, so $\bar{x} \neq 0$. Then $x^{e_i} \in \mathfrak{p}_i^{e_i}$.